# How to add elements to a bash array?

Tags: arrays, bash

I'm trying to add elements to a bash array, and I cannot figure out why they are not added:

```
$ cat /tmp/tmp.bash
#!/bin/bash

declare -a base=(
"python"
"python-setuptools"
)

packages=( "${base[*]}" "tools" "oracle" )
echo "$packages"

$ /tmp/tmp.bash
python python-setuptools
$
```

In the output, we only see the `base` array elements, but not the two I added.

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$packages` expands to just the first element. To print all array elements write:

```
echo "${packages[@]}"
```

Similarly, when you expand `$base` you should use `@` not `*`. `*` causes `"python"` and `"python-setuptools"` to be concatenated into a single array entry: `python python-setuptools"`.

```
packages=( "${base[@]}" "tools" "oracle" )
```

Also note that there's no need to quote simple string literals. You could omit them.

```
base=(
    python
    python-setuptools
)

packages=("${base[@]}" tools oracle)
echo "${packages[@]}"
```

Comment: You can also use `+=( )` to append to an array: `packages+=(tools oracle)`